# Need help in proving that $\frac{\sin\theta - \cos\theta + 1}{\sin\theta + \cos\theta - 1} = \frac 1{\sec\theta - \tan\theta}$

Tags: trigonometry

We need to prove that $$\dfrac{\sin\theta - \cos\theta + 1}{\sin\theta + \cos\theta - 1} = \frac 1{\sec\theta - \tan\theta}$$

I have tried and it gets confusing.

Comment: @Mahesh The LHS isn't well defined. The denominator is $0\,$ $\leftarrow$ this comment was pre question edit.

Comment: Write the right hand side in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$ and cross multiply.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to make it take up less vertical space -- this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have any strong feelings if this is open or not; that I reopened it is basically an artificat of a quirk of the system.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$$\frac{\sin\theta-\cos\theta+1}{\sin\theta+\cos\theta-1}$$

$$=\frac{\tan\theta-1+\sec\theta}{\tan\theta+1-\sec\theta}(\text{ dividing the numerator & the denominator by} \cos\theta )$$

$$=\frac{\tan\theta-1+\sec\theta}{\tan\theta-\sec\theta+(\sec^2\theta-\tan^2\theta)} (\text{ putting } 1=\sec^2\theta-\tan^2\theta) $$

$$=\frac{\tan\theta+\sec\theta-1}{\tan\theta-\sec\theta-(\tan\theta-\sec\theta)(\tan\theta+\sec\theta)}$$

$$=\frac{\tan\theta+\sec\theta-1}{-(\tan\theta-\sec\theta)(\tan\theta+\sec\theta-1)}$$

$$=\frac1{\sec\theta-\tan\theta}$$

---

Alternatively using [Double-angle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle.2C_triple-angle.2C_and_half-angle_formulae) formula by putting $\tan\frac\theta2=t,$

$$\text{ LHS= }\frac{\sin\theta-\cos\theta+1}{\sin\theta+\cos\theta-1}=\frac{\frac{2t}{1+t^2}-\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}+1}{\frac{2t}{1+t^2}+\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}-1}$$

$$=\frac{2t-(1-t^2)+1+t^2}{2t+(1-t^2)-(1+t^2)} =\frac{2t+2t^2}{2t-2t^2}=\frac{1+t}{1-t}\text{assuming }t\ne0$$

$$\text{ RHS= }\frac1{\sec\theta-\tan\theta}=\frac1{\frac{1+t^2}{1-t^2}-\frac{2t}{1-t^2}}=\frac{1-t^2}{(1-t)^2}=\frac{1+t}{1-t} \text{assuming }t-1\ne0$$

Comment: @Ovi, thanks. Hope I could clear the idea.

Comment: Great! Simplest of all the answers

Comment: @MaheshNatarajan, thanks. How about my other answer?

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\sin\theta -\cos\theta +1}{\sin\theta +\cos\theta -1}= \frac{1}{\sec\theta - \tan\theta}$$

By taking $$\mbox{L.H.S ( Left hand side )}  = \frac{\sin\theta -\cos\theta +1}{\sin\theta +\cos\theta -1} = \frac{2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}+2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}}{2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}-2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}}$$ 
[By applying $1-\cos\theta = 2\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}$]

Which after simplification  gives : $$\frac{\sin\frac{\theta}{2}+ \cos\frac{\theta}{2}}{\cos\frac{\theta}{2}-\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}$$

Now taking R.H.S we get : 
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sec\theta - \tan\theta} &= \frac{\cos\theta}{1-\sin\theta}\\ 
&= \frac{\cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}+\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}-2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}} \\
&= \frac{(\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}-\sin^\frac{\theta}{2})}{(\cos\frac{\theta}{2}-\sin\frac{\theta}{2})^2} \\ &= \frac{\sin\frac{\theta}{2}+ \cos\frac{\theta}{2}}{\cos\frac{\theta}{2}-\sin\frac{\theta}{2}}\\ &= \mbox{L.H.S ( Left hand side )}\end{align},$$
where the second equality comes from applying $\cos\theta = \cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}-\sin^2\frac{\theta}{2}$ and $\sin\theta = 2\sin\frac{\theta}{2}\cos\frac{\theta}{2}$.

Comment: Nice work, sultan +1. (Hint: when formatting trig functions, use `\<trig-function` like `\sin\theta` to get $\sin \theta$ instead of `sin\theta`, where you get $sin\theta$.

Comment: @amWhy, just thought this method and added it to my answer, then found your solution. Needed to remove it which did cost me two revisions. Anyway, good work $+1$

Answer (score 2):

These kind of questions often benefit from the identity $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ in conjunction with Pythagorean trig identitities. Here,

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin t-\cos t+1}{\sin t+\cos t -1}&=\frac{(\sin t+1)-\cos t}{(\sin t+\cos t) -1}\cdot\frac{(\sin t+1)+\cos t}{(\sin t+\cos t) +1}\\
&=\frac{\sin^2 t+2\sin t+1-\cos^2 t}{\sin^2 t+2\sin t\cos t+\cos^2 t -1}\\
&=\frac{2\sin^2 t+2\sin t}{2\sin t\cos t}\\
&=\frac{\sin t+1}{\cos t}\\
&=\tan t+\sec t\\
&=(\tan t+\sec t)\frac{\tan t-\sec t}{\tan t-\sec t}\\
&=\frac{\tan^2 t-\sec^2 t}{\tan t-\sec t}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sec t-\tan t}\\
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $\displaystyle{\sin\theta=\frac{a}{c}}$ and $\displaystyle{\cos\theta=\frac{b}{c}}$ such that $\displaystyle{a^2 + b^2=c^2}$.

$$\displaystyle{\frac{sin\theta - \cos\theta + 1}{\sin\theta+\cos\theta -1}}$$ $$\displaystyle{=\frac{a-b+c}{a+b-c}}$$

Now $\displaystyle{\tan\theta=\frac{a}{b}}$ and $\displaystyle{\sec\theta=\frac{c}{b}}$. Hence, $$\displaystyle{\frac{1}{\sec\theta-\tan\theta}}$$ $$\displaystyle{=\frac{1}{\frac{c}{b}-\frac{a}{b}}}$$ $$\displaystyle{=\frac{b}{c-a}}$$

Let us assume that $$\displaystyle{=\frac{a-b+c}{a+b-c}\neq\frac{b}{c-a}}$$

This simplifies to $$\displaystyle{a^2 + b^2\neq c^2}$$

This is obviously false. Hence, $$\displaystyle{\frac{a-b+c}{a+b-c}=\frac{b}{c-a}}$$

**QED**

Comment: Aren't you **proving** an identity by first **assuming** the identity is true?

Comment: @User58220- Yes. But on assuming this, I've come upon an expression that cannot be refuted. Had I made an erroneous assumption, I would never have arrived upon a mathematically true expression. But if this is a little difficult to digest as of now, we can assume $\displaystyle{\frac{a-b+c}{a+b-c}\neq\frac{b}{c-a}}$. Then we'll get $\displaystyle{a^2 + b^2\neq c^2}$, which is a **contradiction**.

Comment: Why not taking $c=1$?

Comment: @Taladris- yes you can. My proof is just a little more general, where $c$ can $\neq 1$

Comment: @AyushKhaitan Your contradiction proof is right, but your other statements are wrong.  "If $P$, then $Q$" does not prove $P$ just because $Q$ is true.  (Think, for example, of multiplying both sides of $1=2$ by $0$.)

Comment: @AlexanderGruber- Thanks. The relevant edits have been made. But could you tell me in what cases my assertion "if $P$, then $Q$, then $P$ just because $Q$" is true. It seems to be true whenever you're not multiplying by zero or; another example is $\lfloor 3.4\rfloor=\lfloor 3.2\rfloor$. i.e. you're doing something to equate both sides regardless of a difference in values.

Answer (score 1):

multiply numerator and denominator by $(1-\sin\theta)$.
$$\dfrac {\sin\theta-\cos\theta+1}{\sin\theta+\cos\theta-1}\times \dfrac{1-\sin\theta}{1-\sin\theta}$$
$$\dfrac {\sin\theta-\sin^2\theta-\cos\theta+\sin\theta\cdot\cos\theta+1-\sin\theta}{(\sin\theta+\cos\theta-1)(1-\sin\theta)}$$
$$\dfrac {1-\sin^2\theta-\cos\theta+\sin\theta\cdot\cos\theta}{(\sin\theta+\cos\theta-1)(1-\sin\theta)}$$
$$\dfrac {\cos^2\theta-\cos\theta+\sin\theta\cdot\cos\theta}{(\sin\theta+\cos\theta-1)(1-\sin\theta)}$$
$$\dfrac {\cos\theta(\cos\theta+\sin\theta-1)}{(\sin\theta+\cos\theta-1)(1-\sin\theta)}$$
$$\dfrac {\cos\theta}{1-\sin\theta}$$
$$\dfrac {1}{\dfrac{1-\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}}$$
$$\dfrac {1}{\dfrac{1}{\cos\theta}-\dfrac{\sin\theta}{{\cos\theta}}}$$
$$\dfrac {1}{\sec\theta-\tan\theta}$$