# how to show $\frac{1+\cos x+\sin x}{1+\cos x-\sin x} = \frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}$

Tags: trigonometry

I know that $\frac{1+\cos x+\sin x}{1+\cos x-\sin x} = \frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}$ is correct. But having some hard time proofing it using trig relations. Some of the relations I used are 
$$
\sin x \cos x= \frac{1}{2} \sin(2 x)\\
\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x= 1\\
\sin^2 x  = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \cos(2 x)\\
\cos(2 x) = 2 \cos^2(x)-1
$$
And others. I tried starting with multiplying numerator and denominator with either $\cos x$ or $\sin x$ and try to simplify things, but I seem to be going in circles.

Any hints how to proceed?

Comment: **Hint:** You only need to use one of the relations you listed.

Comment: @SteveH, See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426981/need-help-in-proving-that-frac-sin-theta-cos-theta-1-sin-theta-cos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\frac{1 + \cos x + \sin x}{1 + \cos x - \sin x}$$
$$= \frac{(1 + \cos x + \sin x)(1 + \cos x + \sin x)}{(1 + \cos x - \sin x)(1 + \cos x + \sin x)}$$
$$= \frac{1 + \cos^2 x + \sin^2 x + 2\cos x + 2\sin x + 2\sin x \cos x}{1 + 2\cos x + \cos^2 x - \sin^2 x}$$
$$= \frac{2(1 + \cos x + \sin x + \sin x \cos x)}{1 + 2\cos x + 2\cos^2 x - 1}$$
$$= \frac{2(1 + \cos x)(1 + \sin x)}{2\cos x(1 + \cos x)}$$
$$= \frac{1 + \sin x}{\cos x}$$

Comment: I would recommend using the `align` environment to make the flow of your answer more clear, but I like the $\lozenge$ look of it too much. :)

Comment: I left it as such because of the diamond actually :-)

Comment: I also like how the "middle fraction" dividing line is more bold too to better indicate the "symmetry." It's tempting to put $\frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}$ on top of the $\lozenge$ structure to make it look more like a $\lozenge$ isn't it? Haha. If only!

Comment: If only indeed! I tried to put something on top, but nothing I tried made much sense :D

Comment: Check out [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1185113/domain-and-range-word-problem) recent problem from a textbook...see my comment lol. What an **awful** job by the person who wrote that textbook. Goodness.

Comment: t = -2 is completely justified, essentially you go back in time by 2 units and then throw the ball. It is just time travel 101 :P ;-)

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up! I really need to take time travel 101...I want to mess with some things and be born as Gauss. Maybe I can make that happen now!

Answer (score 3):

You have to prove that
$$
\frac{1+\cos x+\sin x}{1+\cos x-\sin x} = \frac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}.\tag{1}
$$
Note that $(1)$ may be expressed as follows by cross-multiplying:
$$
\underbrace{(\cos x)(1+\cos x+\sin x)}_{\text{LHS}}=\underbrace{(1+\sin x)(1+\cos x-\sin x)}_{\text{RHS}}.\tag{2}
$$
Now all you have to do is expand the LHS and RHS to see that they are equivlant:

We have
\begin{align}
\text{LHS} 
&= (\cos x)(1+\cos x+\sin x)\tag{definition}\\[0.5em]
&= \cos x +\cos^2(x)+\cos x\sin x\tag{expand}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\text{RHS} &= (1+\sin x)(1+\cos x-\sin x)\tag{definition}\\[0.5em]
&= 1+\cos x-\sin x+\sin x+\sin x\cos x-\sin^2(x)\tag{expand}\\[0.5em]
&= 1+\cos x+\sin x\cos x-\sin^2(x).\tag{simplify}
\end{align}
Now compare the LHS and RHS. We clearly have that
$$
\cos^2(x)=1-\sin^2(x)\Longleftrightarrow \cos^2(x)+\sin^2(x)=1,
$$
and we know this famous result to be true (or easily established otherwise). Hence, we have proved $(1)$.

Answer (score 3):

Rearrange and Cross multiply

it is required to prove that

$$\dfrac{\cos x +1 +\sin x}{1-\sin x +\cos x} = \dfrac{1+\sin x}{\cos x}$$ or

$$ \cos^2 x + \cos x (1 +\sin x ) = (1-\sin^2 x) + \cos x (1 +\sin x ) $$ or

$$  \cos x (1 +\sin x ) =  \cos x (1 +\sin x ). $$

Comment: That was cute. +1

Answer (score 0):

#### Hint:

$$= \frac{(1 + \cos x + \sin x)(1 - \cos x + \sin x)}{(1 + \cos x - \sin x)(1 - \cos x + \sin x)}$$