# Show that $\frac{1-\cos2x+\sin2x}{1+\cos2x+\sin2x} = \tan x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Show that $$\frac{1-\cos2x+\sin2x}{1+\cos2x+\sin2x} = \tan x$$

I have substituted the expansions for $\cos2x$ and $\sin2x$ and gotten, after simplification:

$$\frac{1-\sin x\cos x + 2\sin^2x}{1+\sin x\cos x-2\sin^2x}$$
I'm not sure how to carry on. I factored out the $\sin x$, but ended up with
$$\frac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x}$$

I haven't been taught that as equal to $tan x$.

Comment: You need to check your $\sin 2x$ and $\cos 2x$ expansions - and if need be expand $1$ in a similar way.

Comment: Your first rewrite is wrong.

Comment: Related: [Proving this trig identity: $\frac{1+\cos\theta+\sin\theta}{1+\cos\theta-\sin\theta}=\frac{1+\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1446213/proving-this-trig-identity-frac1-cos-theta-sin-theta1-cos-theta-sin-the). You can find other related questions using Approach0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{1-\cos 2x + \sin 2x}{1+\cos 2x + \sin 2x} &=\frac{1-(1-2\sin^2 x) + 2\sin x \cos x}{1+(2\cos^2 x -1) + 2\sin x \cos x} \\
&=\frac{2\sin^2x +2\sin x \cos x}{2\cos^2x + 2\sin x \cos x}
\end{align}

Can you simplify from here?

Comment: Okay. I factor out the two. Then, I factor out sin from the top and cos from the bottom. How do I get rid of $(1+cosx)$ in the numerator and $1+sinx$ in the denominator?

Comment: After getting rid of $2$ and if you factor out $\sin x$ form the numerator, you should be left with $\sin x + \cos x$. Try to check that. Also verify your working for the denominator as well.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use $$\cos2x=2\cos^2x-1=1-2\sin^2x\text{ and }\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x$$

Or use [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution#The_substitution)

Or $$\dfrac{1+\sin2x}{\cos2x}=\dfrac{(\cos x+\sin x)^2}{\cos^2x-\sin^2x}=\dfrac{\cos x+\sin x}{\cos x-\sin x}\text { assuming }\cos x+\sin x\ne0$$

Apply [Componendo et Dividendo](https://www.qc.edu.hk/math/Junior%20Secondary/Componendo%20et%20Dividendo.htm)

Answer (score 1):

By [Tangent half-angle formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_formula) with $t=\tan x$

- $\cos 2x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$
- $\sin 2x=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}$

we have

$$\frac{1-\cos2x+\sin2x}{1+\cos2x+\sin2x}=\frac{1-\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}+\frac{2t}{1+t^2}}{1+\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}+\frac{2t}{1+t^2}}=\frac{1+t^2-1+t^2+2t}{1+t^2+1-t^2+2t}=\frac{2t+2t^2}{2+2t}=t$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1-\cos2x+\sin2x}{1+\cos2x+\sin2x} = \frac{1- (2\cos^2x-1)+2\sin x .\cos x}{1+ 2\cos^2x-1+2\sin x .\cos x}$$
$$ = \frac{2- 2\cos^2 x +2\sin x .\cos x}{ 2\cos^2 x +2\sin x .\cos x} = \frac{1- \cos^2 x +\sin x .\cos x}{ \cos^2 x + \sin x .\cos x}$$
$$ = \frac{\sin^2 x +\sin x .\cos x}{ \cos^2 x + \sin x .\cos x} = \frac{\sin x (\sin x + \cos x )}{ \cos x (\sin x + \cos x )} = \frac{\sin x }{ \cos x } = \tan x$$

Comment: Please pay attention to your formatting when you write an answer.