# How do we prove that $\frac{\sin{2\theta} + \cos{2\theta} + 1 }{\sin{2\theta-} \cos{2\theta}+1} = \cot{\theta}$?

Tags: trigonometry

$$\frac{\sin{2\theta} + \cos{2\theta} + 1 }{\sin{2\theta-} \cos{2\theta}+1} = \cot{\theta}$$

I stopped here -

$\frac{(2)\sin\theta\cos\theta+ (1 + (2)\cos\theta)}{(2)\sin\theta\cos\theta + (1-(2)\cos\theta) }$

Comment: Use $\sin(2\theta)=2\sin\theta\cos\theta$ and $\cos(2\theta)=\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta$

Comment: yeah, but it gets harder as you go through it

Comment: \begin{align*}
\frac{\sin(2\theta) + \cos(2\theta) + 1}{\sin(2\theta) - \cos(2\theta) + 1} = \frac{\sin(2\theta) + 2\cos^{2}(\theta)}{\sin(2\theta) + 2\sin^{2}(\theta)} = \frac{2\cos(\theta)(\sin(\theta) + \cos(\theta))}{2\sin(\theta)(\cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta))} = \cot(\theta)
\end{align*}

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia I stopped here $\frac{(2)\sin\theta\cos\theta+ (1 + (2)\cos\theta)}{(2)\sin\theta\cos\theta + (1-(2)\cos\theta) }$

Comment: @ايادايمن Please add your efforts in the body of the question so that I can provide you a full answer.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia I added it in the question

Comment: @ايادايمن I have provided the full answer.

Comment: Duplicate: [Show that $\frac{1-\cos2x+\sin2x}{1+\cos2x+\sin2x} = \tan x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3885812).

Comment: According to the formula after your "I stopped there", you seem to believe that $\cos(2\theta)=2\cos\theta.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac{\sin(2\theta) + \cos(2\theta) + 1}{\sin(2\theta) - \cos(2\theta) + 1} & = \frac{\sin(2\theta) + 2\cos^{2}(\theta)}{\sin(2\theta) + 2\sin^{2}(\theta)} \tag{1}\\\\
& = \frac{2\cos(\theta)(\sin(\theta) + \cos(\theta))}{2\sin(\theta)(\cos(\theta) + \sin(\theta))} \tag{2}\\\\
& = \cot(\theta) \tag{3}
\end{align*}

$(1)$: I applied the identities $\cos(2\theta) = \cos^{2}(\theta) - \sin^{2}(\theta) = 2\cos^{2}(\theta) - 1 = 1 - 2\sin^{2}(\theta)$.

$(2)$: I applied the identity $\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$ and pulled out $2\cos(\theta)$ as well as $2\sin(\theta)$.

$(3)$: I simplified the obtained expression.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: It was a duplicate: [Show that $\frac{1-\cos2x+\sin2x}{1+\cos2x+\sin2x} = \tan x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3885812).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for the feedback, I was not aware of it. Next time I am going to pay more attention.

Comment: Anyway I don't think the post contained enough "efforts" to deserve an answer.

Comment: @AnneBauval can you edit it please to show the correction?

Comment: Átila Correia gave you a detailed answer, and there was nothing to "edit to show the correction" in your post, except erase the obviously erroneous formula, and replace it by deeper thoughts, but nobody could do that for you.