# Simple question on trigonometry identities of sec and tan

Tags: trigonometry

Please, I want to know different methods to prove following identity

$$\frac{\tan \theta + \sec\theta - 1}{\tan\theta-\sec\theta + 1}=\frac{1+\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$$

Comment: It will help you and future users a great deal if you learn how to type the equations yourself instead of relying on pictures.  Visit [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a tutorial on how to type in MathJax on this site.

Comment: What is the method that you already know?  This helps us to give you other methods.

Comment: Did you try writing the LHS in terms of sin and cos and simplifying?

Comment: @Gregory Grant    No I only use tan and sec as provided in question. I have not done it with sin and cos.

Comment: RHS is $\sec \theta +\tan \theta$, may be it helps

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426981/need-help-in-proving-that-frac-sin-theta-cos-theta-1-sin-theta-cos

Answer (score 3):

Notice, $$LHS=\frac{\tan\theta+\sec\theta-1}{\tan\theta-\sec\theta+1}$$
$$=\frac{\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}+\frac{1}{\cos\theta}-1}{\frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}-\frac{1}{\cos\theta}+1}$$
$$=\frac{\sin\theta-\cos\theta+1}{\sin\theta+\cos\theta-1}$$
$$=\frac{(\sin\theta-\cos\theta+1)((\sin\theta+\cos\theta)+1)}{(\sin\theta+\cos\theta-1)((\sin\theta+\cos\theta)+1)}$$
$$=\frac{\sin^2\theta+2\sin \theta+1-\cos^2\theta}{(\sin\theta+\cos\theta)^2-1}$$
$$=\frac{\sin^2\theta+2\sin \theta+\sin^2\theta}{\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta+2\sin\theta\cos\theta-1}$$
$$=\frac{2\sin^2\theta+2\sin \theta}{1+2\sin\theta\cos\theta-1}$$
$$=\frac{2\sin\theta(1+\sin \theta)}{2\sin\theta\cos\theta}$$
$$=\frac{1+\sin \theta}{\cos\theta}=RHS$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from the complicated side.

$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\tan\theta+\sec\theta-1}{\tan\theta-\sec\theta+1}&=\frac{\tan\theta+\sec\theta-1}{\tan\theta-\sec\theta+1}\times\frac{\cos\theta}{\cos\theta}\quad\text{(Multiply by $1=\frac{\cos\theta}{\cos\theta}$ to simplify)}\\
&=\frac{\sin\theta+1-\cos\theta}{\sin\theta-1+\cos\theta}\\
&=\frac{(\sin\theta+1)\left(1-\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta+1}\right)}{\cos\theta\left(\frac{\sin\theta-1}{\cos\theta}+1\right)}\quad\text{(Forcefully factoring out the terms we need)}\\
&=\frac{(\sin\theta+1)\left(1-\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta+1}\right)}{\cos\theta\left(\frac{\sin\theta-1}{\cos\theta}\times\frac{1+\sin\theta}{1+\sin\theta}+1\right)}\\
&=\frac{(\sin\theta+1)\left(1-\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta+1}\right)}{\cos\theta\left(\frac{\sin^2\theta-1}{\cos\theta(1+\sin\theta)}+1\right)}\\
&=\frac{(\sin\theta+1)\left(1-\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta+1}\right)}{\cos\theta\left(\frac{-\cos^2\theta}{\cos\theta(1+\sin\theta)}+1\right)}\\
&=\frac{(\sin\theta+1)\left(1-\frac{\cos\theta}{\sin\theta+1}\right)}{\cos\theta\left(1-\frac{\cos\theta}{1+\sin\theta}\right)}\\
&=\frac{1+\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}\quad\text{(Cancelling out common terms)}
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$LHS = \frac{\sin\theta+1-\cos\theta}{\sin\theta - 1+ \cos\theta}$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow\frac{\sin\theta+1-\cos\theta}{\sin\theta - 1+ \cos\theta} = \frac{1+\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$$
$$\Longleftrightarrow(\sin\theta+1-\cos\theta)\cos\theta = (\sin\theta - 1+ \cos\theta)(1+\sin\theta)$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow\sin\theta\cos\theta+\cos\theta-\cos^2\theta = \sin\theta - 1 + \cos\theta + \sin^2\theta-\sin\theta+\cos\theta\sin\theta$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow-\cos^2\theta = -1 + \sin^2\theta$$

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying by $\cos\theta$ the num and the denom

$$\frac{\tan \theta+\sec \theta-1}{\tan \theta-\sec \theta+1} = \frac{\sin \theta+1-\cos \theta}{\sin \theta-1+\cos \theta}$$
Now setting the equality and deleting the fractions
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin \theta+1-\cos \theta}{\sin \theta-1+\cos \theta}&=\frac{1+\sin \theta}{\cos \theta}\\
\cos \theta + \cos \theta - \cos^2  \theta &= \sin  \theta + \sin^2  \theta-\sin  \theta-1+ \cos  \theta+\sin \theta \cos  \theta\\
-\cos^2  \theta &=\sin^2  \theta-1.
\end{align}