# Trigonometric equations having + - pattern

Tags: trigonometry

How to solve trigonometric equations by just looking at the form...

For e.g., proving $$\cos A - \sin A + \dfrac {1}{\cos A + \sin A} - 1 = \csc A + \cot A$$

First of all I know the LHS is in basic T-ratio so I don't need to convert them but if I divide LHS by $\cos A$ it changes to $\tan A$ and $\csc A$. How do I solve questions like these which have + - pattern?

Although I did it but I want to do some other way as well.

Comment: Please reformat your equations with MathJax so that we know exactly what you're talking about in the equations (mainly the division)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426981/need-help-in-proving-that-frac-sin-theta-cos-theta-1-sin-theta-cos

Comment: Please check this [link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to use MathJax.