Integrating $\int\frac{\csc x+\cot x-1}{1+\cot x-\csc x}\,dx$

I need to integrate this particular function
$$\int\frac{\csc x+\cot x-1}{1+\cot x-\csc x}\,dx$$

but my teacher as well as the integral calculator gave me a different answer from my own. There is no way both the answers are the same, but in different forms.
I did this method, using trigonometric half angle formulae, :
$$
\begin{aligned}
& I=\int \frac{\operatorname{cosec} x+\cot x -1}{1+\cot x-\operatorname{cosec} x} d x \\
&\\
& \operatorname{cosec} x=\frac{1}{\sin x}; \qquad \cot x=\frac{\cos x}{\sin x} \\
&\\
& \therefore \quad \frac{\operatorname{cosec} x+\cot x-1}{1+\cot x-\operatorname{cosec} x}=\frac{\frac{1+\cos x}{\sin x}-\frac{\sin x}{\sin x}}{\frac{\sin x}{\sin x}+\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}-\frac{1}{\sin x}}=\frac{1+\cos x-\sin x}{\sin x+\cos x - 1} \\
&\\
& \cos x=\cos ^2 \frac{x}{2}-\sin ^2 \frac{x}{2} ; \qquad \sin x=2 \sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2}; \qquad 1=\cos ^2 \frac{x}{2}+\sin ^2 \frac{x}{2} \\
&\\
& \therefore I=\int \frac{\cos ^2 \frac{x}{2}+\sin ^2 \frac{x}{2}+\cos ^2 \frac{x}{2}-\sin ^2 \frac{x}{2}-2 \sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2}}{2 \sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2}+\cos ^2 \frac{x}{2}-\sin ^2 \frac{x}{2}-\cos ^2 \frac{x}{2}-\sin ^2 \frac{x}{2}} d x \\
& =\int \frac{2 \cos ^2 \frac{x}{2}-2 \sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2}}{2 \sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2}-2 \sin ^2 \frac{x}{2}} d x \\
& =\int \frac{2 \cos \frac{x}{2}\left(\cos \frac{x}{2}-\sin \frac{x}{2}\right)}{2 \sin \frac{x}{2}\left(\cos \frac{x}{2}-\sin \frac{x}{2}\right)} d x \\
& =\int \cot \frac{x}{2} d x \\ 
& =\ln \left|\sin \frac{x}{2}\right| + C
\end{aligned}
$$
Is my method wrong or what? I can't seem to figure out.

We appreciate you showing your work, but it's really important to use MathJax instead of an image to present mathematics.  It's much easier to read and everyone on this site is volunteering their time to help others, so making questions user-friendly is common courtesy.  Please edit your post to use MathJax.  Here's a primer:  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Tell us what the teacher's answer is. It's possible they are equivalent but just look different.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. There's a small error at the end:$$\int\cot\frac{x}{2}\mathrm{d}x=\color{blue}{2}\ln\left|\sin\frac{x}{2}\right|+C.$$

Welcome to Math.SE! ... In the final integration, you're missing a factor of $2$ (to account for a $u$-substitution of $u=x/2$, $du=dx/2$). ... I don't know what your teacher or the integral calculator obtained (you should say), but Mathematica gave $2\log|\cos(x/2)|+2\log|\tan(x/2)|+C$, which is certainly equivalent to $2\log|\sin(x/2)|+C$.

@RobertShore   I am sorry. I don't know how to use this. I am new here. But I'll learn and will not make this mistake next time.

@MPW The teacher's answer was ${\ln x |1- \cos x| +C}$ . But you need not bother with this anymore. I understood where I went wrong.

@J.G. Oh yeah... Thank you!

@Blue Yeah... Thank you for the correction! The teacher's answer was ${\ln x |1- \cos x| +C}$ and that is equal to ${2\ln x |sin (x/2)|}$

Just to give an alternative way: Numerator = $\csc x + \cot x-1 = \csc x + \cot x-(\csc^2 x- \cot^2 x )= (\csc x + \cot x)(1+\cot x - \csc x)$. So you just need to integrate $\csc x + \cot x$. This is probably how your teacher obtained $\log|1-\cos x|$

Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426981/need-help-in-proving-that-frac-sin-theta-cos-theta-1-sin-theta-cos

Your Answer is:- 2*ln|(sin(x/2))|+c
--> ln|(sin(x/2))^2|+c
cos(x)=1- 2*(sin(x/2))^2
-->  2*(sin(x/2))^2=1-cos(x)
Hence = ln|1-cos(x)|+c which is same as yours.

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.
